# Why dataframe.values is very slow

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called df. When I do the following:

> A = df.values
>   Then when I check:
>   A is df.values
>   It returns False.

Even though when I check `type(A)` and `type(df.values)`, both rerun the type as numpy.ndarray

Also, my df has mixed data of strings and numerical data. The call `A[10,1]` is significantly faster than the call `df.values[10,1`

I am wondering what is happening when I call df.values?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For DataFrames of mixed type calling `.values` converts multiple blocks (for each dtype) into one numpy array of a all-encompassing dtype. This conversion can be slow for large frames.

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.]]).values
Out[11]: array([[ 1.,  2.]])

In [12]: pd.DataFrame([[1, 2., 'a']]).values
Out[12]: array([[1, 2.0, 'a']], dtype=object)
```

A example with timings:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000))

In [22]: %timeit df.values  # no conversion
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.72 µs per loop

In [23]: df[1] = 'a'  # add column of object dtype

In [24]: %timeit df.values  # conversion to object dtype
1000 loops, best of 3: 681 µs per loop
```

*You can see how data is stored in the BlockManager via the `._data` attribute.*

To answer the question, since this values attribute is *calculated* each time the return numpy array has a different id / memory address and so `A is df.values` is False. You need to use something like numpy's array_equal:

```
In [31]: df.values is df.values
Out[31]: False

In [32]: np.array_equal(df.values, df.values)
Out[32]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I understands how the underlying works for .value call.